# React & Material-UI Pagination - Hooking up Material-UI's component to React-Router

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-router, material-ui

I have a component that handles pagination for real estate listings pulled in from an API. It's successfully displaying the appropriate amount of listings and is handling creating the appropriate amount of links.

It looks like this:

```
const Paginations = ({ listingsPerPage, totalListings, paginate }) => {
    const pageNumbers = [];

    for(let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalListings / listingsPerPage); i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    return (
         <ul>
           {pageNumbers.map(number => (
               <li key={number}>
                   <a onClick={() => paginate(number)} href="#">
                       {number}
                   </a>
               </li>
           ))}
       </ul>
    );
}

export default Paginations;
```

I would like to replace the basic `ul` with Material-UI's [Pagination](https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/) component. I would also like to hook it up to `React-Router` and for it to handle routing to the appropriate page i.e. the component's URL is `/search/`, if you click the the 3 it would take you to `/search?page=3`.

The example Material-UI gives looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';
import PaginationItem from '@material-ui/lab/PaginationItem';

export default function PaginationLink() {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/inbox']} initialIndex={0}>
      <Route>
        {({ location }) => {
          const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
          const page = parseInt(query.get('page') || '1', 10);
          return (
            <Pagination
              page={page}
              count={10}
              renderItem={(item) => (
                <PaginationItem
                  component={Link}
                  to={`/inbox${item.page === 1 ? '' : `?page=${item.page}`}`}
                  {...item}
                />
              )}
            />
          );
        }}
      </Route>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
}
```

How can I incorporate the example with the router into my Paginations component?

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-uhczc?file=/demo.js

please find the above link, which will help you to create the material ui router pagination.

Try changing the url ex: https://....../5 (the pagination will be set to 5)

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, so other user can understand it better. Also, it would be better to paste the relevant code to your answer, in case the link you provided shuts down.